# Zoom in and out all children of a canvas?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I'm having some problems with Canvas event ManipulationDelta, and It seems to be a function for manipulation of the whole canvas itself.

Im looking for a event where I use two fingers to pinch the screen. On pinch it should zoom in or out the children of that canvas element.

Is there a way to do this out of the box with xaml/c# or am I better of with a lib, in that case which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are targeting Windows Phone 7, you can detect gestures via Toolkit.GestureService. Find out more on this article: [WP7 GestureService in depth | key concepts and API](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-gestureservice-in-depth--key-concepts-and-api).

Unfortunately, for Windows Phone 8 you must do the gesture detection yourself, there is no gesture API for it yet.